# Using robocopy without providing username and password between Jenkins slave and master

Tags: deployment, jenkins, robocopy

I would like to know if there is a safe and secure way to use Robocopy between a master and slave to do some deployments.

I've tried the plugin called Copy to slave but actually I don't want to copy all files first and then perform the copying on the slave.

So I also tried something like

```
ROBOCOPY "\\myMaster\c$\folder" "C:\Program Files"
```

But then it requires a username and password to be provided (Access is denied). Providing a username and password using Jenkins is not so secure I think. Is there a way this can be provided in a secure way?

I'm also looking at options like using DeltaCopy or WinSCP. Maybe this are the better options than using ROBOCOPY?

Comment: In order to give you the right answer, what kind of files to you want to transfer between your master and your slave? Is it some artifacts build on the master?

Comment: It's for a windows forms application so most of the are dll's, .exe ....